# API Support For Logging In A B2B Customer

Tags: ios, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

Does Shopify provide API Support for logging in a B2B Customer in a custom storefront, in this case using the mobile-buy-sdk for an iOS and Android app? I can only find customerAccessTokenCreate which requires you to register a unique e-mail that doesn’t exist in the system and does not work with B2B Customers.

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/storefront/2023-04/mutations/customerAccessTokenCreate

I’m looking for documentation/API support for logging in an existing B2B user, does anyone know if this is possible for native iOS and Android apps that use the mobile-buy-sdk.

Currently I can only register new users with unique e-mails, I need to login existing users that are already customers of a company, the user type that is referred to in the link below.

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/b2b/checkout#setting-up-login

I've managed to implement registration and login of new user accounts, but they use login and password. I need to use the Online store new login mechanisms that sends a 6 digit OTP code and logs in an existing user.